# parsing Error, .HTML -> string in JSON, but there's Special Character in HTML file

Tags: html, json, flutter, dart

I am trying to convert a HTML Text into a json variable as String.
The HTML is this

```
"Herosim in  21<sup>st</sup> 21ˢᵗ Century: The Example of \"Dexter\""
```

A problem is coming from the 'ˢᵗ' in the middle. I tried

```
 Achievement.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {

JsonUtf8Encoder();
titel = json['titel'] != null
    ? parseFragment(json['titel']).text
    : json['titel'];
```

}

```
Text(
                        "LP: ${achievement.punkte.toString()}, ",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)
                    ),
```

The Result is now,

[image]

I have found https://mothereff.in/html-entities this website but have no idea for now. Even a small hint would be very helpful.

Comment: Have you tried using RichText instead of Text?

Comment: ah the Html file I cannot fix. It's from a customer..

Comment: I mean have you tried using the RichText widget instead of the Text widget when displaying in Flutter?

Comment: I am going to try now

Comment: Alright. If it works, you can add an answer to the question with the working code.

Comment: It's still the same :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237058/discussion-between-zac-and-jiho).

Answer (score 1):

I found out it's because of default Custom Fonts for entire app. When you use `Roboto` or `Arial` fonts, it doesn't have any problems.

```
fontFamily: 'Roboto'
```

or none.